# Ubuntu Launcher bottom item not linked with shortcut-key

Tags: launcher

Usually when I hold down the <kbd>super</kbd>, the items on the launcher each get a number which I can press to switch to that application. Recently however, the bottom item is never assigned a number and I cannot switch to it using <kbd>super</kbd>+`<num>`. If only Firefox is open then I do not get a number at all. If I open Thunderbird, Firefox is assigned the number 1, but now Thunderbird (which is at the bottom) doesn't get a number. This happens regardless of how many apps I open.

Is this a bug, or is there a way to fix it?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Here is a screenshot to better explain the problem:
[image: Launcer bottom item inactive]

Comment: Although I am aware of that feature it is not one I typically use, but more often demonstrate to new users as among their many options.  I've never seen numbers greater than 10 offered, so if you have more than 10 items in your launcher, that could be the problem.  

What I'm about to suggest is not a direct solution to your entire problem, but applies to your issue of switching between programs already loaded, in your case, firefox.  May I recommend you try pressing SHIFT-ALT- up arrow to navigate between already loaded software?